# if comparison behaves unexpectedly

Tags: batch-file

I am running the following Batch program under Windows 7:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set iterations=2
set flag=1
echo Beginning at !TIME! with iterations %iterations%
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %iterations%) do (
  echo   Starting iteration %%x at !TIME!
  REM flag 
  if %flag%==0 do (
    echo       flag=%flag% and flag=0
  )
  if %flag%==1 do (
    echo       flag=%flag% and flag=1
  )
)
```

I was expecting the above program to emit output similar to this:

```
C:\Temp>test.bat
Beginning at 17:47:48.18 with iterations 2
  Starting iteration 1 at 17:47:48.18
      flag=1 and flag=1
  Starting iteration 2 at 17:47:48.18
      flag=1 and flag=1
C:\Temp>
```

But what I see is this:

```
C:\Temp>test.bat
Beginning at 17:47:48.18 with iterations 2
  Starting iteration 1 at 17:47:48.18
      flag=1 and flag=0
  Starting iteration 2 at 17:47:48.18
      flag=1 and flag=0
'do' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
      flag=1 and flag=1
C:\Temp>
```

I do not understand why:

1. The first 'if' clause is ever executed ... 'flag' equals 1, and to my way of thinking, this string comparison should return false
2. Both 'if' clauses are executed during the second iteration
3. The execution of the loop the second time produces the error message related to 'do'

Interestingly, if I force string comparison in the second 'if', I can eliminate the error message related to 'do', i.e.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set iterations=2
set flag=1
echo Beginning at !TIME! with iterations %iterations%
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %iterations%) do (
  echo   Starting iteration %%x at !TIME!
  if %flag%==0 do (
    echo       flag=%flag% and flag=0
  )
  if "%flag%"==1 do (
    echo       flag=%flag% and flag=1
  )
)
```

Which then produces this output:

```
C:\Temp>test.bat
Beginning at 17:58:27.09 with iterations 2
  Starting iteration 1 at 17:58:27.10
      flag=1 and flag=0
  Starting iteration 2 at 17:58:27.10
      flag=1 and flag=0
      flag=1 and flag=1
C:\Temp>
```

But even that I find puzzling:

4. Why does forcing a string comparison (I'm doing a string comparison anyway) eliminate the 'do' error?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if %flag%==1 do (
    echo       flag=%flag% and flag=1
  )
```

this should be

```
 if !flag!==1  (
    echo       flag=!flag! and flag=1
  )
```

`DO` comes from for loops . remove it from if conditions.And under delayed expasnion is better to access our variables with `!`

Comment: +1, but the delayed expansion is not needed for flag in this case. True, it is generally more reliable for more situations, but that information obscures the fundamental problem with the OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

[npocmaka found the source of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954883/1012053) - DO is not used with IF statements.

All that is left is to explain the output of your faulty code.

Both your IF statements are intended to be within a parenthesized FOR DO block. But the DO in each IF statement is treated as an external command (non existent) and the `(` is treated as a parameter to the DO command - so it does not start a new block!

Your first IF statement is never true, so it never tries to execute `DO (`, so no error. Your next ECHO is always executed, and then the `)` closes the FOR /F loop!

Once your loop finishes all iterations, the next IF statement is executed, and this time it is TRUE. So it attempts to execute `DO (` and raises the error because DO is not a valid command.

Then your next ECHO is executed, and the final `)` is ignored. This is a peculiar quirk of batch parsing. When the parser is looking for a command, and it is not within a parenthesized block, and it finds a `)`, then it simply ignores the `)`. Not only that, it also ignores the rest of the line.

So the following can be thought of as a harmless comment *as long as it does not appear within a parenthesized block*.

```
) This is effectively a comment, as long as not within a parenthesized block
```

Here is your code with modified indentation to show how the parser sees it.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set iterations=2
set flag=1
echo Beginning at !TIME! with iterations %iterations%
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %iterations%) do (
  echo   Starting iteration %%x at !TIME!
  REM flag
  if %flag%==0 do (
  echo       flag=%flag% and flag=0
)
if %flag%==1 do (
echo       flag=%flag% and flag=1
```

When you add quotes to your 2nd IF statement, you only did so on one side. It compares `"1"` with `1`, which is always FALSE, so it never tries to execute `DO (`, and no error is generated. If you added quotes to both sides, then you would get the error again:

```
if "%flag%"=="1" do (
```

Answer (score 1):

Generation 6,886 of `delayedexpansion`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note also the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

Where flags are involved, the situation changes again. `set "flag="` will ensure a flag is cleared. `set "flag=somethingelse"` will ensure it is set (the value is not relevant.) Using `if defined flag (doiftrue) else (doiffalse)` works on the **run-time** (current) status of `flag` - not the **parse-time** value.

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.

---

"Forcing" a string-comparison.

Um, you need to be careful. In an `if` statement, if **both** arguments are **syntactically** valid integers, then the comparison will be performed as though the strings were integers. This even occurs where the string is out-of-range of the 32-bit variable used. This can lead to bizarre results:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a maxint=2147483647
FOR %%v IN (10, 010, 012, 0xa ) DO CALL :evaluate %%v
ECHO =============
FOR %%v IN (2147483647, 2147483646, 2147483648, 21464836470) DO CALL :evaluate2 %%v
ECHO =============
FOR %%v IN (2147483647, 2147483646, 2147483648, 21464836470) DO CALL :evaluate2 k%%v
ECHO =============
IF "987" lss "1234" (ECHO "987" is less than "1234") ELSE (ECHO "987" is NOT less than "1234")
IF "987" gtr "1234" (ECHO "987" is greater than "1234") ELSE (ECHO "987" is NOT greater than "1234")
GOTO :EOF

:evaluate
ECHO comparing %1 to 10
IF %1==10 (ECHO %1 is equal to 10) ELSE (ECHO %1 is NOT equal to 10)
IF "%1"=="10" (ECHO "%1" is equal to "10") ELSE (ECHO "%1" is NOT equal to "10")
GOTO :eof

:evaluate2
ECHO comparing %1 to k%maxint%
IF %1 equ k%maxint% (ECHO %1 is equal to k%maxint%) ELSE (ECHO %1 is NOT equal to k%maxint%)
IF %1 lss k%maxint% (ECHO %1 is less than k%maxint%) ELSE (ECHO %1 is NOT less than k%maxint%)
IF %1 gtr k%maxint% (ECHO %1 is greater than k%maxint%) ELSE (ECHO %1 is NOT greater than k%maxint%)
GOTO :eof
```

To force a string comparison, you need to ensure that the values compared are not valid numerical constants within `cmd`'s rules. Clasically, enclose in quotes. Note that `1` and `"1"` are **not** the same string.

Another issue that can trip up the unwary is that a string-comparison is made left-to-right so attempting to compare numeric values using strings is not as straight-forward as it might seem.

Comment: All good info, but I don't see how any of this relates to the OP's problem.

Comment: @dbenham: ISTM OP has more than one problem and more than one question. The first is not appreciating the `if` statement syntax. Then there is the difference between a string and a numeric comparison. The variable being interrogated is suspiciously named `flag` which is a big red - er, flag saying "I'm likely to be changed." Thus I'm hoping to pre-empt the inevitable "why doesn't `%var%` appear to change within the `%%x` loop?"

Comment: @dbenham : **but** there is an even more intriguing question, which I'll break into another question. Look very carefully at the reported output for the routine at the very end of OP's question. I'll admit that my response so far has been `"air code"` - but well, perhaps it's 2am and I'm not thinking quite straight, but ISTM there's something very interesting going on here.

Comment: I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25959716/1012053) fully explains all behavior of the OP's code.

Comment: @dbenham. Certainly. You've got that nailed. Must remember to wait for my blood-alcohol level to rise to normal before tackling these things. Nevertheless, I believe that it's valid to forestall the why-doesn't-%var%-work-"properly"-in-a-loop and to tackle the string-comparison vs integer-comparison matter that OP has apparently misunderstood. Too many questions in one, really. But a lot of useful info was shaken out - which is all to the good.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I now have a stronger understanding of how the batch parser works, thank you for the detail.

To a first approximation, my error lay in using 'do' to extend an 'if' clause.  Corrected, 
and functioning, code below:

`@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set iterations=2
set flag=1
echo Beginning at !TIME! with iterations %iterations%
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %iterations%) do (
  echo   Starting iteration %%x at !TIME!
  if %flag%==0 (
    echo       flag=%flag% and flag=0
  )
  if %flag%==1 (
    echo       flag=%flag% and flag=1
  )
)`

This produces the expected output:

```
C:\Temp>test.bat
Beginning at  7:12:58.81 with iterations 2
  Starting iteration 1 at  7:12:58.82
      flag=1 and flag=1
  Starting iteration 2 at  7:12:58.82
      flag=1 and flag=1

C:\Temp>
```

Thank you for your assistance,

--sk

Comment: You should probably accept npocmaka's answer, as I think it directly led to your solution.